# Regex to Identify an URL Parameter Not Knowing Which Parameter It Will Be

Tags: http, haproxy

So I've been working on building out an haproxy cluster (1.5.x) and hit a snag where for a particular webapp I'm wanting to pitch API GETs to a read-only app cluster and the PUTs into a much smaller write cluster.

I've tried using a *path_reg*, which doesn't seem to want to match anything beyond a filename. The urlp derivatives seem to be what I should be using, but their proper usage has eluded me. The one tricky nuance with the URL parameters I'm trying to capture and differentiate all begin with either a "get" or "set" something...but the parameters do not have values. From what I've understood or attempted to, the urlp derivatives generally expect there to be a value associated with a parameter, so it seems like I can't simply use something like:

```
acl api_gets urlp_reg(get) (get?){1}
```

from an URL with parameters like:

```
/api.foo?apikey=stuff&param1=foo&getsomething&param2=bar
```

Similarly, *path_reg* seems to not pick up anything beyond a filename, so rudimentary testing of trying to match the following as a proof of concept were also fruitless:

```
acl path_sanity_check path_reg ^\/api\.foo\?apikey.*
```

Whereas simply making the regex pattern *^/api.foo* will pick up where the requests are being sent to.

*Should* I be using urlp_reg for this even if the parameter(s) don't have values? What alternatives are there if not using an urlp derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path fetches the *path*.  The query isn't part of the path.  [`capture.req.uri`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#7.3.6-capture.req.uri) fetches the full URI.

Although sloppy, you could match that with something like this:

```
acl foo capture.req.uri -m reg [&\?]get
```

The character class escaping might require adjustment, but the idea is to find either `?get` or `&get` in the request URI.

If you are building a new cluster, use HAProxy 1.6, which has a number of new, useful fetches and converters, plus optional Lua integration for more complicated logic.

`urlp_reg` is the wrong solution, because the regex match is for the *value* of the parameter, not its name... and you don't have values.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't stumble on the *capture.req.uri* before. I had a gut feeling trying the urlp derivatives that they were always going to fail because the particular parameters I wanted didn't have values as you indicate and confirm.

Your suggestion did just the trick - thanks a lot!